# hi. for those who read the book of albert camus "the stranger" in what perspective or theory it can be seen?

Tags: existentialism, identity, camus

for those who read the book of albert camus "the stranger" in what perspective or theory it can be seen? it's a work of philosophy but i'm misselead. thanks for answering

Comment: See [Albert Camus](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/camus/) and [Existentialism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/existentialism/)

Comment: When I had to read the novel in high school, my teacher presented it as "existentialism". But Camus rejected the existentialist label and called himself absurdist. I think that also fits the novel better. https://www.thescientificphilosopher.com/answers/2018/9/29/how-do-you-distinguish-between-existentialism-and-absurdism#:~:text=The%20existentialist%20mantra%20(at%20least,constant%20striving%20to%20find%20meaning.

Comment: Camus was preoccupied with Absurdism. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absurdism

Comment: This is about Camus and *The Plague*. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/77217/interpretation-of-an-existentialist-quotation-by-camus